# C# client GO server

Tags: c#

I am new to go and trying to learn it. I have written simple Hello world server and trying to access it through my `C# console application`. Here is my server:

```
   package main
   import (
    "fmt"
    "net/"
    "github.com/labstack/echo"
)
func main(){
    fmt.Println("Welcome to the Server!")
    e:=echo.New()
    e.GET("/", func(c echo.Context) error {
    return c.String(http.StatusOK, "Yallo from the Server! \n")
    })
}
```

I am using `labstack/echo` package for this.It works with my `Mozilla`.
Here is my client.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            string responseString = string.Empty;
            var task = new Task(async () =>
             {
               responseString = await client.GetStringAsync("localhost:8000");
             });
            task.Start();
            task.Wait();
            Console.WriteLine(responseString);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

But I am getting error:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Net.Http.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Only 'http' and 'https' schemes are allowed.

Comment: change `client.GetStringAsync("localhost:8000");` to `client.GetStringAsync("http://localhost:8000");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`async` keyword causing problem on console application. I do not know why, everybody says something different. this will work.

```
var client = new HttpClient();
string responseString = string.Empty;
responseString = client.GetStringAsync("http://localhost:8000").Result;
Console.WriteLine(responseString);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 1):

Note the [`GetStringAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh551746(v=vs.118).aspx) method requires a URI, and that [URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier) needs a protocol/scheme. In other words, try this:

```cs
responseString = await client.GetStringAsync("http://localhost:8000");
```

Comment: Yeap this does not give an error but gives just an empty string.

Comment: I recommend breaking this problem down so you can isolate the problem. For example, start by making the call synchronously (without the Task and await, you're blocking for it anyway) and see if your server is returning the expected value at all. Then you can worry about making the client more sophisticated. :)

Comment: As I aforementioned the server is returning the string in my Mozilla. Do you mean `GetStringAsync` method already waits for its completion?

Comment: Ah, nevermind my suggestion: the HttpClient's retrieval methods are all async.

Comment: Ok. What about the empty string in my C# client. Any suggestions?